# Init QList<MyStruct> as static class member gives LNK2001 error

Tags: c++, qt, static-members, qlist, lnk2001

This is best explained by the code itself. I want to use a `QList<MyStruct>` as a static member, but get a linker error 2001 (`LNK2001`). The code is in the same order in file `MyClass.h`

```
struct MyStruct{
    double  x;
    ...
};
typedef QList<MyStruct> MyStructList;

class MyClass
{
....
private:
    static MyStructList _myValues; // does not work => LNK2001
           MyStructList _myValues; // Test 1 OK
    static QList<int> _myValues; // Test 2 OK
```

Any hints? **Eran's answer (see comment below) is the right hint. SOLVED**

```
LNK2001:
error: LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static class QList<struct>
```

Comment: Are you actually _defining_ those data members, or merely declaring them?

Comment: Are you defining `_myValues` in some .cpp file? `MyStructList MyClass::_myValues`?

Comment: And is it exact linker error message corresponding to `static MyStructList _myValues;` ?

Comment: eran has already given the answer, I forgot to add it in the corresponding cpp file. If you want (eran) you can add it as an answer, will accept it. Thanks for the prompt response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yet another case of forgotten static member definition... `MyStructList MyClass::_myValues` should have been placed in one of the project's .cpp files.